# Divergence of the sum of the reciprocals of a subset of the prime numbers

Tags: calculus, prime-numbers, geometric-progressions

I had the following question related to the sum of the reciprocals of the prime numbers restricted to a certain subset.

Let $T, c > 1$ be real numbers. Let $A=\cup_{k \geq 0} [Tc^{2k},Tc^{2k+1}]$ and $B=\cup_{k \geq 0} [Tc^{2k+1},Tc^{2k+2}]$. It should be true that $\sum_{p \in A} 1/p$ and $\sum_{p \in B} 1/p$ diverge, and it should be a consequence of the prime number theorem, but I was not able to conclude this last fact.

We know by Pigeonhole Principle that at least one of them diverges, but I need to show both of them do.

Comment: Why the  pigeonhole principle ?  The sum of $\sum_A+\sum_B=\infty,$ hence one of the summands is infinite.

Comment: Yes, I mean that idea, which is basically Pigeonhole.

Answer (score 1):

Write $$\sum _{p\leq X}\frac {1}{p}=\log \log X+B+E(X)$$ and $K=Tc^{2k}$. If $$E(X)=o(1/\log X)\hspace {10mm}(\star )$$ then $$\sum _{K<p\leq Kc}\frac {1}{p}=\log \log (Kc)-\log \log K+\mathcal O\left (E(K)\right )=\log (1+\log c/\log K)+o\left (\frac {1}{\log K}\right )\sim \frac {\log c}{\log K}=\frac {\log c}{\log T+2k\log c}=\frac {1}{2k}$$ so for some $k_0$ $$k\geq k_0\implies \sum _{K<p\leq Kc}\frac {1}{p}\gg \frac {1}{k}$$ so $$\sum _{p\in A}\frac {1}{p}=\sum _{k\geq 0}\sum _{K<p\leq Kc}\frac {1}{p}\geq \sum _{k\geq k_0}\sum _{K<p\leq Kc}\frac {1}{p}\gg \sum _{k\geq k_0}\frac {1}{k}=\infty .$$

I'm not sure myself how to get $(\star )$ but Theorem 6.10 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.0442.pdf gives it.

Comment: Nice! The only question I have is why is the error term in those sums summable? More precisely, for the first approximation.

Comment: then let me make things more precise, hold on

Comment: mm, better now? or still something missing?

Comment: What I meant is the following. I do agree that $\sum_{K < p \leq Kc} 1/p∼\log\log(Kc)−\log\log K$, but perhaps the error term in that is roughly say $1/k$ (this is far from being true, but it's just to fix ideas). So $\sum_{K < p \leq Kc} 1/p∼\log\log(Kc)−\log\log K -1/k$ might be the case and so when adding, then we get a subtraction of $1/k$ too and that won't diverge. I guess we need to guarantee that the error term is sufficiently small (not $1/k$ as pointed out) so that when adding those error terms, we get a finite number and therefore the approximation provided is correct.

Comment: sorry, you are right - i overlooked needing a more precise error term.  in the "usual" approximation to $\sum _{p<X}1/p$ the error is $\ll 1/\log X$ which (as you say) isn't good enough to get your result.  but it's possible to improve the error term - see my edited (agian) answer

Comment: Thanks! I do agree now that it is correct. Furthermore, I think we can just use a lighter result, the following. Let's just use that the error term is $\mathcal{O}(1/\log(x))$, we can find a sufficiently large $K_0$ so that for all $K \geq K_0$ we get $|E(cK)-E(K)| \leq \frac{\log(c)}{4\log(K)}$. And a $K_1$ such that for $K\geq K_1$, we also have $\log(1+\log(c)/\log(K))\geq \log(c)/(2\log(K))$. By joining both inequalities, we get the desired result.

Comment: mm, not sure about your first $E-E$ error... maybe/probabbly i'm not seeing somethinf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145410/discussion-between-amarchionna-and-tomos).